# How to find out whether a string include digit(s)

Tags: python, string

How do I find out whether a string has digit(s). For example, `"Te6st1"` has digits (6 and 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\d+', "Te6st1")
['6', '1']
```

If you want them as integers, you can then call `int` on the result:

```
>>> [int(n) for n in re.findall(r'\d+', "Te6st1")]
[6, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `isdigit()` function with something like this

```
>>> s = "Te6st1"
>>> results = [(char,char.isdigit()) for char in s]
>>> results
[('T', False), ('e', False), ('5', True), ('s', False), ('t', False), ('1', True)]
```

You can also use the `filter` operator to get all the digits

```
>>> digits = filter(lambda x:x.isdigit(), s)
>>> digits
'51'
```

Hope it helps